# Closure of a subgroup in an infinite Galois extension

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

Let $K/F$ be a Galois extension. Let $H$ be a subgroup of $G=\mathrm{Gal}(K|F)$. 
Let $\mathcal{N}=\lbrace N\subseteq G\text{ }|\text{ } N= \text{Gal}(K|E)\text{ where }[E:F]<\infty \text{ and } E/F \text{ is Galois}\rbrace$.

Let $\overline{H}$ be the closure of $H$. (with respect to the Krull topology). Prove that $$\overline{H}=\cap_{N\in\mathcal{N}}HN.$$

Comment: Is this an assigned (e.g. homework) problem? Are you asking others to prove it for you? If “no” to both questions, why don’t you tell us what ideas you’ve had and how far you’ve gotten with them?

Comment: It is an assignment problem. I only have the idea that $\overline{H}=\text{Gal}(K|L)$ where $L$ is the fixed field of $H$.

Comment: Is it true that $HN$ is open for any $N\in\mathcal{N}$ ? This is because 
$HN=\cup_{h\in H}hN$ and $hN$ is open for all $h\in H$. As $HN$ is a union of open sets, it is open.

Comment: Is it true that $HN$ is closed for all $N\in\mathcal{N}$ ?